# Android - floating shadows issue with videoview

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have a problem with a shadow that appears when starting an activity containing only RelativeLayout and LinearLayout, ImageView and a VideoView.

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/page"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/training"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/video"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center">


                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/video_pause"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/video_play"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the Manifest part of the activity:

```
<activity
            android:name="package.try"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

this is the image of the activity:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/YYyfPjd.png]

I was able to make disappear the shadow by changing the theme of Activity in:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

but it is just a hack to do not see the shadow but the problem remains because even the onBackPressed () does not work when I view this shadow.
Does anyone know why this happens?
Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
public class prova extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private ImageButton button;
    private String uri;

    Dialog dialog;
    View video;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prova);

        video = (View) findViewById(R.id.video);
        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);


        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        uri = "android.resource://package/try/raw/v2444";
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        MediaController controller = new MediaController(prova.this);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(controller);
        controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myVideoView.seekTo(1);
        myVideoView.start();

        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });


        myVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myVideoView.pause();


                return true;
            }

        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myVideoView.requestFocus();
                myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
                MediaController controller = new MediaController(prova.this);
                myVideoView.setMediaController(controller);
                controller.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myVideoView.start();

            }


        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like this happens because of the theme, but if the `onBackPressed()` method doesn't work, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, It depends by the theme the presence of the shadow, but it is as if there is an object or a property for which it appears. The VideoView and Layout default does not have shadows in any theme, why never appears? I also noticed that when I click the shadow disappears. I add the code for clarity.